# how to get history['val_accuracy'] from ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, training-data

I'm using `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`

When i fed it to `model.fit` like that

```py
history = model.fit(
    train_data_gen,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_freq=validation_freq,
    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=2)]
)
```

it works fine, but there is no actual validation data, so my callback doesn't work, as well as plotting, since `history.history['val_accuracy']` simply doesn't exist, i have only two items in this dict accuracy and loss

so my main question how to get it work like that

```py
history = model.fit(
    x=train_data_gen,
    y=val_data_gen,
)
```

but w/o

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using python generator as input.
```

Comment: If you provide validation data, validation accuracy will be available as val_acc, not val_accuracy. Also if you are using keras, why are you not using fit_generator?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy val_acc - doesn't exist in newer versions of keras, only `accuracy` and `val_accuracy`.  

*not using fit_generator*

because my dataset small? are there any other benefits?

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using? If you are using generators, you have to use fit_generator, only tf.keras will let you pass generators to fit (they are trying to merge both APIs).

Comment: i'm using Arch Linux, so everything is bleeding edge - keras 2.4.0

Comment: You should be using fit_generator then, that will probably solve the issue

Comment: that funny that i didn't get any error, and my learning process works somehow lol

Comment: `Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.` meh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in `model.fit` arguments

`validation_freq=validation_freq` instead of `validation_steps=validation_freq`

so after that everything works just fine, `val_accuracy` is available finally

```py
history = model.fit(
    x=train_data_gen,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=validation_freq,
    callbacks=[
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=2),
        ModelCheckpoint('models/m-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.4f}.h5')
    ],
).history
```